# How to find and replace particular first string and last string from a table records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table **url_table** with following data:

```
url_table:

Keywords:
---------
panasonic-es-sl41
philips-hp-8105
-philips-hp-8310
mitsun-mit-555-
casio-mj-120d-
belkin-f8-n801-qe
```

I want to delete "**-**" from first and last letter of the records without affecting other records in the table. What is the MySQL query to replace the '-' as i required ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to eliminate **leading** and **trailing** dashes `-` from column values then [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) is a good fit for this. Meaning if a column value has two or more dashes at the begging or at the end they all will be removed.

```
UPDATE url_table
   SET keywords = TRIM(BOTH '-' FROM keywords)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3595/1)** demo

or

```
UPDATE url_table
   SET keywords = TRIM(BOTH '-' FROM keywords)
 WHERE keywords LIKE '-%'
    OR keywords LIKE '%-'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f4f2d/3)** demo

In both cases result after update

```
|          KEYWORDS |
---------------------
| panasonic-es-sl41 |
|   philips-hp-8105 |
|   philips-hp-8310 |
|    mitsun-mit-555 |
|     casio-mj-120d |
| belkin-f8-n801-qe |
```

---

**UPDATE:** Now if you want to remove **only first** and **only last** dashes in a column value and leave any subsequent ones then you can do something like this

```
UPDATE url_table
   SET keywords = CONCAT(REPLACE(LEFT(keywords, 1), '-', ''), 
                         MID(keywords, 2, LENGTH(keywords) - 2), 
                         REPLACE(RIGHT(keywords, 1), '-', ''))
 WHERE keywords LIKE '-%'
    OR keywords LIKE '%-'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a562/1)** demo for that case

Comment: will it trim '-' from first and last in a record ?

Comment: Thanks bro, Your query is good. I using it to solve my issue. Thank you :)

Comment: +1 for SQLFiddle, I was not aware about that such online tool :)

Comment: @balajimca You are very welcome :) Please see updated answer for additional explanation on how trim works and a possible side effect if you have subsequent dashes at the beginning or end of values and you want to keep them. I hope that is not your case.